# Prevent w-multiplication for GLSL vec4 outputs?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm working on my first deferred shading implementation, and I made some render targets with GL_RGBA32F internal format, but when I try to output a vec4 from my fragment shader to the render target the values get multiplied by the w component before they are written to the texture.

Yes, I could just divide by w when I use them later, but that seems wasteful.  Is there a way to prevent them from getting w-multiplied in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

> when I try to output a vec4 from my fragment shader to the render target the values get multiplied by the `w` component before they are written to the texture.

They are only multiplied by the `w` component - or written in a more obvious way - the `a` component when ypu have set up some alpha blending. (like `GL_SRC_ALPHA` source blend factor). You should disable blending when writing to the gbuffer - transparency wouldn't work with deferred shading in that way anyway.

Comment: Thanks!  That wasn't obvious to me, and I probably wouldn't have figured it out quickly.